# custom mapview not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, nosuchmethoderror

I am implementing custom mapview to override on touch event . Here goes the code

```
public class CustomMapView extends com.google.android.maps.MapView {
public GlympseMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
    super(context, apiKey);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static boolean LOG_DEBUG = true;
public static String TAG = GlympseMapView.class.getName();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (LOG_DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "on touch event :: map view called");
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

Here is the layout definition :

```
  <com.packagename.mock.CustomMapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0lq9O_Wyv7aby-na7rHhAR13GgzD5ItYdkiogVw"
```

I have an activity extending MapActivity and i did setcontent().

> But while running i get 10-07 20:08:46.918:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5615): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: CustomeMapView(Context,AttributeSet)
>   10-07 20:08:46.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at
>   java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643) 10-07
>   20:08:46.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472) 10-07 20:08:46.918:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)

Note:I have set the internet permission,coarse location . And included uses-library tag . 
What am i doing wrong .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code class name is CustomMapView and no constructor found like class name..check this,,

http://nocivus.posterous.com/double-clicktap-detection-on-a

http://pa.rezendi.com/2010/03/responding-to-zooms-and-pans-in.html